# Why is this happening to C pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

When I'm using this code, the output is incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    
    int a, *ptr;
    a=10;
    *ptr=&a;
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output is: `634927948`

But when I'm using this code, It's giving the correct output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a=10;
    int *ptr=&a;
    printf("%d",*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is: `10`

Comment: `*ptr = &x` and `int *ptr = &x` are *very* different, the leading `int` changes the meaning of the line completely. The first reaches "through" whatever address is already in `ptr` and puts the address of `x` there. The second creates a new pointer, and puts the address of `x` in `ptr`, **not** in the address already held in `ptr`.

Comment: How many warnings did you get for the first code? Some warning about making integer from pointer? Some warning about using variable without assigning a value first? Don't ignore warnings. They are meant for your support, nothing else. If you did not get some warnings, you should urgently increase warning level. For GCC you can use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: @Gerhardh I was using an online C compiler(programiz.com). Unfortunately didn't get any warnings or errors. But thank you anyway. I'll switch to the GCC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `*ptr=&a;` means "write the address of `a` into the memory `ptr` points to". Note that `int *ptr;` is not initialized, so you're writing to a random memory location.

  - Thus, `*ptr` is that address of `a`: `(size_t)&a == 634927948`.
- `int *ptr=&a;` means "`ptr` is a pointer that points to the memory where `a` is located".

  - Thus, `*ptr` is the value *at* the address of `a`, which is `a == 10` itself

Answer (score 0):

The following line is dereferencing the pointer before assignment. The value at the memory location of `ptr` is assigned the memory address of `a`.

```cpp
*ptr = &a;
```

Instead the line should be :

```cpp
ptr = &a;
```

`ptr` will point to the memory location of `a`.

If you use :

```cpp
*ptr = a;
```

The memory location that the pointer is pointing to (already) will be assigned the value of `a`.